# Finding Code coverage for rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simplecov

Problem Statement: To find the code coverage for a rails project. We are using a separate repository for test framework which follows RSpec-Capybara structure. Are there any tools/gems to find the coverage where tests are outside the dev repository?

Also, We have already used 'simplecov' gem for finding coverage of unit tests, so can it be used in a case where dev and test repo are different? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

This gem https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov should fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Hi...I have already used it for the unit test cases. BUT as described above we have a separate test repo for BDD test. So, how to use simplecov? Can you please provide more info